# Async Task runs for second time only when device is connected to computer

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm stuck on this bug for a while now.

I have an `AsyncTask` class, it's job is to retrieve data from my server and in the `onPostExecute()` I'm updating my list view.

Everything works just perfect while I'm debugging but when I run it when my device is not connected to the computer, the task runs only for the first search.

This is how I am Calling the Task:

```
task = (DownloadWebpageTask)new DownloadWebpageTask();
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mData);
```

I get no exceptions what so ever but it just won't work more than once.

What's also interesting, is that I start my application (While my device is not connected to the computer), I run a search for the first time -> getting results. Run it for the second time, it'll just hang (like nothing happens) I checked it it doesn't even get to the `doInBackground()`, but then when I plug my device to my laptop it sort of releases it , retrieving the data and every thing works fine.

I don't have any `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` so that's not the problem.

Any help will be very appreciated.

**EDIT:** weird thing i noticed - the 1st search works great. 2nd search doesn't work(75% of the times). 3rd search and up works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

executeOnExecutor() was added in API level 11. Do you want to execute task in parallel or serially? Do you have synchronization mechanism that might be creating trouble? Please check docs developer.android.com/reference/android/os/…, Params...) you may want to try `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, mData)` and see result!

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond! I have tried both serial/threadpool. and both doesn't work. I don't really know what you mean by "synchronization mechanism". but something weird i noticed last night - 1st search is working, 2nd doesn't work, 3rd and up works perfect. Oh,  that's my manifest: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> so I can't see problems with version. Thanks!